# How can I write the following query in Rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I need to write a query that only counts individuals that have not attended an event previously.

Here are the models

```
class Individual < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attendances, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :events, through: :attendances
end

class Attendance < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :individual
end 

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attendances, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :individuals, through: :attendances
end
```

In my view I have 2 different queries. Each query measures event attendance during each fiscal year.

Query for FY 2015:

```
  <%= Event.published.joins( :attendances => :individual ).where( 
  :events => {:fiscal_session => "2014-10-01".."2015-09-30"}
  ).distinct.count(:individual_id) %>
```

Query for FY 2016:

```
  <%= Event.published.joins( :attendances => :individual ).where( 
  :events => { :fiscal_session => "2015-10-01".."2016-09-30"}
  ).distinct.count(:individual_id) %>
```

The problem is that the query for FY 2016 does not ignore individuals that attended an event in FY 2015.

I am using postgresql, and I have tried to write scopes and helper methods that would filter out individuals that attended in FY 2015. But I just haven't been able to figure it out.

For example, here is FY 2015:

```
<%= Individual.joins(attendances: :event).where( 
:events => {:fiscal_session => "2014-10-01".."2015-09-30"}
).group('individuals.id').having('count(attendances.id) > 0').count %>
```

The result is:

```
{2787=>1, 3469=>1}
```

And this is for FY 2016

```
<%= Individual.joins(attendances: :event).where( 
:events => {:fiscal_session => "2015-10-01".."2016-09-30"}
).group('individuals.id').having('count(attendances.id) > 0').count %>
```

The result is this:

```
{2905=>1, 3444=>1, 2787=>1, 2790=>1, 2858=>1}
```

As you can see, `individual_id 2787` is counted twice. I do not want to count `2787` in the query for FY 2016.

What is the proper way to achieve the desired count with Rails and ActiveRecord?

Comment: Just to verify that I understand your question, you want individuals who have attended one or more events in FY 2016, but have attended zero events in every other time period? If that is right, I think you'll have to combine your current query with two "NOT IN" queries to get the time periods before and after FY 2016.

Comment: yes, that is exactly the count I want. I am not familiar with NOT IN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way for you to accomplish what you want to do is with two queries.

```
ignore_individuals = Event
.published
.joins(attendances: :individual)
.where( 
  'events.fiscal_session <= ?', '2015-09-30'
)
.pluck(:individual_id)

Event
.published
.joins(attendances: :individual)
.where.not(individual_id: ignore_individuals)
.where( 
  events: { fiscal_session: "2015-10-01".."2016-09-30" }
).distinct.count(:individual_id)
```

Comment: I approached it this way earlier today, except using a scope. The result of that query yields the same as this query: 

    `Event.published.where( events: { fiscal_session: "2015-10-01".."2016-09-30" } ).distinct.count(:individual_id)`

Comment: aha sorry, yeah. This won't work for what you want to do.

Comment: this is so close. i am getting this error: `column events.individual_id does not exist`

Comment: Your solution works great! The only thing I changed was the second query to this:
`Individual.joins(attendances: :event).where.not( id: ignore_individuals).where( events: { fiscal_session: "2016-10-01".."2017-09-30" ).distinct.count(:individual_id)`

Comment: @don_Bigote this answer creates the `NOT IN` query I mentioned in my above comment, but I think you also want a similar query for the period of time `>=` the period you're interested in, and to eliminate those as well. Also, rather than using `pluck`, if you change that one word to `select`, it will only run one query rather than two. (Actually it will run one query instead of three, because I still think you need to remove events from after the time period you're concerned with).

Comment: ignore_early_individuals = `Event
.published
.joins(attendances: :individual)
.where( 
  'events.fiscal_session <= ?', '2015-09-30'
)
.select(:individual_id)`.  
ignore_later_individuals = `Event
.published
.joins(attendances: :individual)
.where( 
  'events.fiscal_session > ?', '2016-09-30'
)
.select(:individual_id)`

`Event
.published
.joins(attendances: :individual)
.where.not(individual_id: ignore_early_individuals)
.where.not(individual_id: ignore_later_individuals)
.where( 
  events: { fiscal_session: "2015-10-01".."2016-09-30" }
).distinct.count(:individual_id)`

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for: `Individual.includes(:events).where( events: { id: nil } ).count`

These are the people who never attended any events.

Comment: Exactly. That will give me a count of individuals that have not attended an event. How would I use that to get a count of individuals who attended only in 2016

Answer (score 1):

Not positive but if you're looking for a count of individuals who've attended an event in 2016 and your tables have timestamps you I believe you can do

`Individual.joins(:attendances).where("attendances.created_at > ?", "01-01-2016").count`

Comment: This will give me a count of all attendances in 2016. However, I do not want to count any individual who also attended in 2015.